Python Packages . Not installing on IntelliJ Idea (Community Edition) - Attribute Error
I was on IntelliJ Idea Community 2022.2, with the JetBrains' Python Community Edition plugin. I wanted to install the mysql-connector-python package. I tried it from the IDE's own Python Package section but it ended in a error as
afeIndex = self.tree.openElements.i(formattingElement)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'i'

The IDE told to run the following command in terminal. It was showing that if this command doesn't work also, then the problem is out of IDE control. And it too gave the same error.
C:\Users\SK\IdeaProjects\Python_Learn\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
C:/Users/SK/IdeaProjects/Python_Learn/venv/Scripts/python.exe C:/Users/SK/AppData/Roaming/JetBrains/IdeaIC2024.1/plugins/python-ce/helpers/packaging_tool.py install mysql-connector-python

This was not just for that specific package, but any package that I tried installing showed the exact same error. I went to PyCharm Troubleshooting Guide (as the IDE suggested), but found nothing, and then also updated to latest Community 2024.1, but the issue is still the same.
After all that I tried the simple pip command in terminal to install the package, and to my surprise it actually worked, the package was also recognised by Idea. Then why is it that when installing packages by Idea only results in this error ?
